# How would this be traced back?

Tags: malware, tor, forensics

I was thinking about this, and I can't wrap my mind around it.

Assume a person with malicious intentions that has created malware in a virtual machine.

Then, this person, using the Tor browser uploads his malware to a file sharing website (which he doesn't own), and some victim downloads it, and reports him.

How would cyber crime investigators trace the person back? Even if they knew a virtual machine / Tor browser was used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A virtual machine doesn't really affect the tracing, it's still going to have the same IP as the host machine leaving the network. Tor would make it probably unlikely that the user would be caught by traditional police work, it'd have to be a pretty serious attack or operation (think Silk Road Admin level of important) in order to actually try to find a person who's using Tor. Which, if they are important, then it comes back to metadata analysis of the identity that person uses, find accounts that have the same or similar name/details, see if those were accessed outside of Tor.

Operational Security is the number one reason people who use Tor and do malicious/illegal things get caught, they slip up and reveal too much about themselves, or make a technical error and login to an account without Tor once. For some more concrete how they do it, check out the story of how [Ross Ulbricht (the convicted Silk Road creator) was caught](http://motherboard.vice.com/blog/everything-the-silk-road-founder-did-to-get-caught) even though his whole business was on Tor.

Comment: To clarify a bit, it would be enough for the user to log into that sharing website with his account from an unsecure connection once, before or even after uploading that malware.